# Pontryagin Self-Duality

Tags: harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

Near the beginning of Tate's thesis, he showed that the additive group of a complete number field (w.r.t. to any valuation) is Pontryagin self-dual. I am aware of a handful of examples for which it holds, but I would like to know when it holds in general. More precisely, given a group $G$, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions on $G$ for there to exist a topological group isomorphism $G\to\widehat{G}$ ?

Comment: If $H = G\times \widehat{G}$, $H$ is self-dual. (Technically $\widehat{H} = \widehat{G}\times G$, but this is isomorphic to $G\times \widehat{G}$.) There isn't a nice, general classification unfortunately. The question becomes more interesting if you ask which LCA groups that cannot be written as $G\times \widehat{G}$ are self-dual.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thank you for the nice example. Do you know of a nice classification if we assume $G$ is locally compact or abelian?

Comment: I don't! I've tried looking this up myself. There is a sort of classification for LCA groups IIRC. Might be something like they have to be made up of $\Bbb{Q}_p^l$, $\Bbb R^m$, $\Bbb Z^n$ and a compact group (which includes the finite abelian groups). My former advisor Nico Spronk had told me about this, but I couldn't find it. It might be one of those legacy results that are hard to explicitly track down.

Comment: Here's a great paper, actually: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fea9/b47e84777ba35852f3719cfa17978300eefa.pdf ! PDF warning.

Comment: @CameronWilliams That paper takes care of a large and important class of groups I was wondering about. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! If you can unpack this some, it might be good to answer your own question! :) This way it doesn't keep getting bumped by the algorithm, and you can have an answer for users to have access to.